# Problems with glext.h

Tags: windows, linux, macos, opengl, osx-lion

I was just looking through the OpenGL updates on OS X Lion when I found [something that now has me scared to use `glext.h`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/).

So, here's the bug. Lion's OpenGL.framework has a `glext.h` with the following definition.

```
typedef void *GLhandleARB;
```

But the `glext.h` from the OpenGL registry has the following instead.

```
typedef unsigned int GLhandleARB;
```

Now, the trouble is that when building for x86_64 on Lion we have `sizeof(void*)==8`, but `sizeof(unsigned int)==4`. So what do you trust? Lion's header? Or the OpenGL registry's header? Well, of course you trust the system headers, because apparently they claim to know that the ABI on 64-bit Lion has a 64-bit `GLhandleARB` type.

Now, this raises a few issues in my mind about various platforms:

1. If you *must* use Apple's `glext.h`, but Apple's `glext.h` doesn't provide access to anything later than OpenGL 2.1, then how do you get at 3.0+ features on newer cards?
2. Is it unsafe to use the OpenGL registry's `glext.h` on Linux? Or must you use the system's `glext.h` there as well? In that case, question #1 applies here as well.
3. How the heck do you handle things on Windows, where there is *never* a `glext.h` on the system? You clearly can't use a driver vendor's `glext.h`, because different vendors may disagree on the sizes of various types. (Or is that not true?) What's the deal here?

Comment: It's a typedef. Size has nothing to do with it. The important thing with typedefs is to be consistent. As long as there's no *mixing* (e.g. using `GLhandleARB` in one place and an explicit `void*` somewhere else), there's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem.
Just use OS/drivers provided headers.
Or better use multi-platform OpenGL extension loader, that will do the trick for you.
(eg. [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/))

On the other hand in code you will use only GLhandleARB, not other things, so on Mac it will be void* - no problem, on Linux - something different - no problem, on Linux with AMD header - something entirely different - no problem.

Source code is portable across different platforms, not binaries, so I see no problem here.

1) You cant get better OpenGL if you use version served by Apple. So currently you can get max OpenGL 3.2 core profile on 10.7. (heard that Nvidia on some gpus bypassed it with its own headers with OpenGL 3.3, but have no way to check it myself).

2) It depends. If you target OpenGL 2.1 and below, open-source drivers support it, but higher versions are supported only by proprietary drivers, so you should use their headers.
But in code you just put "#include ", and then link against appropriate header and .so library.

3) Do not know how things stand on Win. But probably vendors use glext from OpenGL registry.

But all of this is based on wrong assumption. You DO NOT have to know answers for them. Just use software that already know how to handle this burden. (eg. [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: Source code is portable, not binary, so I see no problem here. <--- Are you kidding me? Binaries need to be portable. Down-voting this response.

Comment: Or to put it blandly, there is no problem since when there will be new glext.h you will need to recompile your code anyway.

Comment: @rutski, no one in the whole world will ever try to make binaries portable. Heck, they don't even have the same format between operating systems! Do the poor guy a favor and take back your minus one. His answer is also correct by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official OpenGL function to get the extensions supported by the instance of OpenGL you are running with: `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`

As for which type you should use, I think this has already been answered Apple's mailing lists: http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2005/Nov/msg00182.html

> Both; the spec doesn't make any claims about what a GLhandleARB is,
>   other than that it's at least 32 bits wide. Note that in the OpenGL
>   2.0 shading language API there is no GLhandle type, it uses GLuint
>   like textures. Also note that GLuint is not an unsigned int on Mac OS
>   X, it's an unsigned long, so you're still screwed :)